# How to show a Visualforce page on the first installati​on of the managed package?

Tags: managed-package, postinstall

I want to show the vf page on the first installation of the managed package, or it can be the custom setting page should open up on installation, where the user will add all the custom settings on the first installation.

Is this possible, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the Custom Settings have to be set manually by the user, or could you use an Apex Post-Install Script to set them?

Comment: The data set will be created by us but the values in the fields will be added by the user.

Answer (score 21):

1. Go to Setup > Customize > Home > **Custom Links**

   [image: Customize Home Custom Links]
2. Create a new custom link to your VF page (eg /apex/ns__pageName)

   [image: Custom Links]
3. Edit your **package** and specify the custom link

   [image]
4. Now a **[Configure]** button will appear after install. Guide your users to click it.

   [image: Configure Package]

Comment: +1 for Herp Derpinson :P Seriously - nice trick though, I didn't know you can add custom buttons to packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Is there any way to enforce the user to configure the application before use.

Comment: I don't think it can be enforced :-(

Comment: I modified Step 1 of this post to include this, but just FYI, the "Custom Link" must be created by going to Setup > App Setup > Home > Custom Links - kind of a strange location, in my mind, confused me the first time I used this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I can think of is use a **Splash Page** for a tab, and make that tab as the **default landing tab** for that application. So, unless the user checks on the checkbox **Don't show this Splash Page again**, the splash page will be displayed as the landing page for your app.