# Including a Read Me in a Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package

I'm creating an app that requires Users to validate a few things in their Org so that the app functions correctly.

Is there a way to include this on the "Success" page after they install the app?  It's a very short 3 step list.

Comment: "[Configure Custom Link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7486/320)" on your package is another worth checking out. In the package description, you could direct the user to the `Configure` button which links to your README.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of communication routes to consider...

- **Default Landing Tab.** I've seen a few apps include a Welcome tab and ensure its the default tab on the Application. This ensures the user sees it first when selecting your app from the application drop down. You can read more [here](https://na11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/dev_tabsetcreate.htm) about setting one of these up.
- **Welcome Email.** You may also want to consider a post install script that sends an email with your read me text in it (and perhaps a link to the welcome page). You can read more about this [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm).

**Configuration Checking:** You certainly should make sure your app fails gracefully if this config is needed for it to function. Make sure you choose carefully the location to make this check, since Force.com native apps can be interacted with in various ways, least of which your VF pages. If its really vital you may want to put prechecks into your triggers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I hadn't even thought of the welcome email - that works perfectly for what I need.

Comment: Excellent, happy to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a "baked in" way to do this from the install success page, no.  That said, there are a few ways you could implement something like this.  You could make sure you app doesn't work until some initial config/questions were submitted. Then you would explicitly state in your install instruction that admins must complete the Setup/Settings/whatever VF page that you surface in your custom app on a custom tab. It's hard to say what would be the most accessible not really know what your app is or does.  Either way, once you have your tab and VF page, you tie it into a Custom Settings object that is set to visibility of Protected. This doesn't let users muck about in the custom setting directly, protected settings are not visible to end users except through your VF page.

You can then drive all of the functioning of your app off that protected settings record, that would be the way to make sure that the app doesn't function otherwise, if those settings either don't exist, or aren't what you want them to be. Absence of this settings record could also redirect people to your setup page as well.  This is one way to do it, and I've made a big assumption that your app is mostly native to SFDC.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the info greenstork!  I'm trying to keep this app very simple, so I don't know if a VF page is the way to go, but very much appreciate the info!