# How can we change the label of tab name in managed package

Tags: apex, tab

Is there any way that we can rename or change the tab name in the managed package. Or we can change the name in packaging org so that old customers can be upgraded and new customers should be able to see the new modified tab name.

Can we do this using post installation script.

Answer (score 2):

**Packaging Org Changes.** You can only edit the Description, Tab Style and Splash Page Custom Link once your tab has been published via a Released Managed package. As per the screen shot below.

[image]

**Subscriber Org Changes**. Users can change the Label and Tab Style of your Tabs btw, via the Setup menu and by editing the Tab in their org to change the style.

[image]

Hope this helps, sadly I'm not aware of a way to script these changes post install.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/creating-custom-button-while-installing-package/11565#11565). The new buttons will be contained in the metadata of your package. You'll need to do some kind of package release that updates the existing release with the new metadata.