# Configure Custom Link is empty when creating a package

Tags: visualforce, package, package-install

I'm trying to create a new package for distribution in the App Store, but I need to populate a custom object via a VF page during installation.  I thought that a custom link would help, but I have an empty list in the "Configure Custom Link" dropdown.

My app is really simple, I have a custom object, a page to configure the custom object, a tab and another VF page to display my app via an iframe.  Everything works as expected but I'm having difficulty in getting this custom link working (assuming that I'm going about this the right way).

Comment: Check this one out: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7486/320

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but now I'm getting an "Id value <long ID> is not valid for the <custom object controller> standard controller" when I try to bring up my VFP to update the field.