# Getting "Id value <long ID> is not valid for the <custom object controller> standard controller" for post install custom link

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, custom-object, package-install

So I've followed the steps outlined in:

[How to show a Visualforce page on the first installati​on of the managed package?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/how-to-show-a-vf-page-on-the-first-installation-of-the-managed-package/7486#7486)

but now I'm getting the following when one of my test users is trying to install the package:

[image: Post-install Error]

All searches show up a custom trigger, but to the best of my knowledge I don't have a custom trigger anywhere.  Testing the VF page in isolation works fine, it's just during the post-install that it's breaking.

EDIT:  Here is the code for the page in question:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Axonify__c">
    <apex:outputPanel id="activatePanel">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Set/Update Axonify Activation Code">
                Please enter your Axonify activation code:<p/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Axonify__c.Code__c}" /><p/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Activate" />
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The first 3 digits of an ID value represents the type of the object and 005 is the type for the User object. So it appears that your code is trying to use a User ID rather than a Axonify object ID somewhere.

Comment: Odd, I have no mention of a User object of any kind in any of my code.  It's rather simple really, all I try to do is set the value for my field with some static text.  Are there any other logs I can look to for more information on the offending VFP or controller?

Comment: Seems as if the page you now show in the question is being passed an "id" parameter that is a User ID. If you append the ID in the error message after a slash in the URL you should find out which user which might help. Sure enable the debug logs.

Comment: Interesting enough the ID is being appended to the post-install page as a query parameter.  Not sure why, but I'll continue digging.  Thanks.